# Why doesn't Nodejs app work on Windows IIS

Tags: node.js, iisnode

I use nodejs app with express i want to host on windows IIS. On my IIS8 nodejs is working. but I got an error 'Cannot GET /node/server.js' and I put rewrite rules in web.config. then I got the following error.

> HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
>   The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid.

I discovered on internet. everyone suggest the following configuration but is not working on my windows

my web.config file is:

```
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
<handlers>
  <add name="iisnode" path="server.js" verb="*" modules="iisnode" />
</handlers>
<defaultDocument>
  <files>
    <add value="server.js" />
  </files>
</defaultDocument>
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="LogFile" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+\.js\.logs\/\d+\.txt$"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="NodeInspector" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="^server.js\/debug[\/]?" />
    </rule>
    <rule name="StaticContent">
      <action type="Rewrite" url="public{REQUEST_URI}"/>
    </rule>
    <rule name="DynamicContent">
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="True"/>
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="server.js"/>
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
<iisnode nodeProcessCountPerApplication="8" watchedFiles="*.js;node_modules\*;routes\*.js;views\*.html"/> 
</system.webServer> 
</configuration>
```

any suggestion?
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration file looks valid. So, you have to install [iis rewrite extension](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and it  works well.